# How to make a counter that counts how many clicks I click each Checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a counter that shows how many checkboxes are in the checkbox list in the html page. My code is as below. The counter that I show in HTML is not updated, why?

I may not be able to capture the checkbox value in the if block.

```js
var clicks = 0;



function checkboxes() {
  var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),


    for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
      if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked == true) {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
      } else {
        clicks -= 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
      }

    }
}
```

```html
<div class="addto-playlists">
  <ol>


    <li>
      <label for="random-1" class="playlist-name">
                    <input id="random-1" type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value=578080>
                    xxxx
                </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="random-1" class="playlist-name">
                    <input id="random-1" type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value=1234>
                    xxxx
                </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="random-1" class="playlist-name">
                    <input id="random-1" type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value=567>
                    xxxx
                </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
<p>clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

Comment: The code is invoked at page load time but not when a click event happens, to trigger on a click event, take a look at [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Also, for thoroughness; your current code has a syntax error due to the `var inputElems` line ending with a comma `,` rather than a semicolon `;`, and your HTML has duplicate `id` attributes, where an ID should always be unique on a whole page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Seems you haven't called checkboxes() method.
2. The logic you've written seems to be wrong. Here is the working solution

```js
document.getElementById("checkbox-list").addEventListener("click", checkboxes);

function checkboxes() {
  var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var clicks = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
    if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked == true) {
      clicks += 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="addto-playlists">
  <ol id="checkbox-list">


    <li>
      <label for="random-1" class="playlist-name">
                    <input id="random-1" type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value=578080>
                    xxxx
                </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="random-1" class="playlist-name">
                    <input id="random-2" type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value=1234>
                    xxxx
                </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="random-1" class="playlist-name">
                    <input id="random-3" type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value=567>
                    xxxx
                </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
<p>clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

Comment: Consider unobtrusive JS pattern of attaching the event listener https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I select checkboxes, the counter increases normally. When I get the checkboxes back, the counter stays at 1 and does not go to 0. Why?

Comment: @Apple Updated the solution. please check now.

Comment: @Ganesh Babu The counter is not updated at all.

Comment: @Apple works fine for me. Can you pls check again

Comment: @Ganesh Babu my bad sorry, thanks